# Why git difftool doesn't start meld on macOS if --dir-diff option is not used?

Tags: git, macos, macos-catalina

I have meld installed with brew on macOS (Catalina).
It is on PATH and can call it normally.

```
>which meld
/usr/local/bin/meld
```

I have `diff.tool` and `merge.tool` set in git's config.

If I say:

```
>git difftool --dir-diff
```

...it shows meld normally as expected in directory-tree mode, but if I say:

```
>git difftool
```

or

```
>git difftool --tool=meld
```

...it shows standard git's diff instead of starting meld.

I've never experienced such behavior on Linux. Is it something macOS specific?
How to fix it?

**UPD:**
I see that the issue is probably only after failed rebase (maybe the same for merge). In case of normal diff of local changes against a commit it works correctly!

Comment: Ah, if you're in the middle of a merge, the index contents are much more complicated than usual. I never actually use `git difftool` and am not sure what it's *meant* to do for this case, but that would explain why it acts differently.

Comment: So I've just spent few hours trying to open meld to resolve my merge conflicts. I tried that, as my vs code failed. Had same behaviour, output in the terminal instead of opening meld app. Thought it was configuration issue but git difftool --dir-diff worked for me as expected. This example saved me more debugging, thanks! ☺️